# How can I get the Wrapper to include the link text?

Tags: css

I'm intentionally pushing my link text below their containing `<div class="box">`

The problem is that the `wrapper` doesn't include the link text. How do I get it to encompass said text?

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rockinthesixstring/SvWf5/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box lowest"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
    <div class="box medium"><a href="#">About</a></div>
    <div class="box"><a href="#">Products</a></div>
    <div class="box medium"><a href="#">Services</a></div>
    <div class="box lowest"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
</div>
```

```css
#wrapper{
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px green;
    position:relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    letter-spacing: 15px;

}

.box a{
    padding-top: 105px;
    display: block;
}

.box{
    width:75px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:red;
    border: solid 1px black;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

.lowest{
    margin-top:50px;
}

.medium{
    margin-top:25px;            
}
​
```

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To #wrapper, add:

```
padding-bottom: 30px;
```

Comment: +1 This is a good way to force it around those lower links, but what happens if those links spread across two lines? I'm hoping to be able to wrap the wrapper around the content based on whatever is inside, rather than push it to a set # of px.

Comment: "white-space: nowrap;" prevents them from going to two lines. Take this out, add a few more blocks and you'll see that padding-bottom still works well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you've already set a specfic height to your `.box` div and pushing your anchor tag by a padding of 105px. This increases the size of your div, height is set fixed at 100px, the wrapper still thinks your div is 100px high.

Either set the appropirate height to the `box` div (height of the div with the red bg **plus** the padding and the height of the anchor tag) or use simply use `min-height` instead of `height`.